# how can I put a "for" in <ul> ...(this method don't work)

Tags: php, jquery, append, html-lists

```
<?php   
echo '<script>var newUL = $("<ul>for($i=1;i<=4;i++){"<li>test</li>";}</ul>");$("#filemanager li").click(function(){$(this).append(newUL);});</script>';
?>
```

I want to put < li > in < ul > tags, using "for" function
I want to generate lines in  an unordered list using for function

Comment: You're going to have to explain that code a lot better  ?

Comment: Is `test` a PHP or Javascript variable?

Comment: "test" is just a text ... I just put wrong code sorry... now the code is edited

Answer (score 1):

(UPDATED AGAIN)

```
<?php
echo '<script>var newUL = $("<ul>';
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
{
    echo "<li>test</li>"; // UPDATED according to new code
}
echo '</ul>");';
echo "\n";
echo '$("#filemanager li").click(function(){$(this).append(newUL);});</script>';
?>
```

Comment: This won't work, javascript won't understand the multiline string without escaping

Comment: take a look here http://editare-prin-ftp.comeze.com/editor.php?hostname=&username=&pwd= when I press on <li> I want it to append in new ul + li ... any idea?

Comment: This code is just the proper way of echoing what you needed.
It will output this : 
var newUL = $("<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>");
$("#filemanager li").click(function(){$(this).append(newUL);});

Comment: This code is working ... This is what I'm looking for . Thank you verry much !

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason at all to use PHP for this task, PHP will not run on click (unless you are using AJAX to make a call to the server). You only need Javascript for this:

```
$("#filemanager li").click(function(){
   $(this).append('<ul><li>test</li></ul>');
});
```

If you need to do this for an arbitrary number of elements:

```
$("#filemanager li").click(function(){
   var elem = '<ul>';
   for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
      elem += '<li>test</li>';
   }
   elem += '</ul>';
   $(this).append(elem);
});
```